# Process.EnterDebugMode throws an exception

Tags: c#, process

When I use the following statement:

```
Process.EnterDebugMode()
```

My program throws an exception:

```
Not all privileges or groups referenced are assigned to the caller
```

I assumed (and from reading here) that it has to do with administrator privilges, however, I'm the administrator account (the only one), tried running it as administrator, turned off firewall, I did anything, but still, doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure why. It suddenly happened, it used to work before.

Does anyone know what can else be the cause? Thanks.